# How to find the path for iCloud folder on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: filepath, icloud, macos-big-sur

I am trying to find the path for iCloud folder, some people suggested `~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/` but I couldn't find that directory.

Comment: You'd need to be more explicit about what "I couldn't find that" means. Did you try to use `cd` in Terminal? Did you try to open that path as a string in a progrm? Given to what function in what language?

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct directory. You can't open it with the Finder (although it is the directory the Finder will show as `iCloud Drive`).

If you start Terminal, you can:

`cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/`

then run

`ls -l` to see the contents.

Answer (score 0):

**Direct Answer**
Use `$HOME` instead of `~` so you don't receive an error when listing the directory.

> user@hostname ~ % ls "~/Library/Mobile Documents"
> ls: ~/Library/Mobile Documents: No such file or directory

**Symbolic Link (symlink)**
A symlink might make things simpler when working with this directory from the command line.

Symlink from Home

```
ln -s "$HOME/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs" iCloudDrive
ln -s "$HOME/Library/Mobile Documents" mobileDocuments
```

Answer (score 0):

For any directory or file, you can drag it from Finder into Terminal, and the full path will be entered. So, for example, you can type "cd " in Terminal (note the space), drag a folder there, and hit return. You are now in that directory.

It is a beautiful thing.